# How can I match three digits with grep?

Tags: regex, grep

Apparently `grep` doesn't really support perl-style regular expression syntax, even with the `-P` option (which is marked as experimental). For example:

```
echo 123 | grep -P \d{1,}
```

yields no results. How can I get this to return `123`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is fine, but depending on the shell in use you may need to quote it, and escape some of its parts, such as `{` and `}` characters.

This produced the desired output for me with bash on Mac OS X:

```
echo 123 | grep "\d\{1,\}"
```