# Finding file names that contains 2 characters and then finding which of those has a number in it

Tags: shell

I have a task that I need to find every /usr/bin file that contains 2 characters. I do that by using: `ls /usr/bin |grep -x ..` and then I get:

`7z ar as at bc cc dc du ex hg id ld m4 nc nl nm od pg pr sg tr ul vi wc xz`.

And now I need to select which of these file names contains numbers, how do I do that?

I can't use find command becuz the task strictly says that I need to use grep or maybe even awk. Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: If you are using Bash shell, you could: `shopt -s extglob ; ls /usr/bin/?([0-9]?|?[0-9])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I match three digits with grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971433/how-can-i-match-three-digits-with-grep)

Comment: Did you try to Google "how to grep a number"? It's a lot faster than getting yelled at by strangers on stack overflow for not doing your research first. Please see [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and list files containing numbers in names with reg exp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991408/find-and-list-files-containing-numbers-in-names-with-reg-exp)

Comment: Do you **have** to use POSIX shell for this? In zsh, ksh or bash, it would be easier.  Also, you write _that contains 2 characters_, but according to your example, it seems that you really mean _that consist of 2 characters_.

Comment: @user1934428 I have to use POSIX shell for this. And yeah I'm not a native english speaker, I did really mean to say that consist of 2 charakters. Sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your approach, you could pipe the output from your `grep` into a second `grep` which selects only lines that have at least one digit:

```
 ls /usr/bin |grep -x ..|grep `[0-9]`
```

Of course your approach is already flawed a bit in the sense that if you happen (just as example) in `/usr/bin` a file containing a newline character, this would not be processed correctly, because `grep` sees the input as a set of lines....